# Dynamic lookup of functions in Clojure namespaces

Tags: clojure

I have a number of namespaces each of which contains a function with the same name, e.g.:

```
(ns myns.resourceX
  ...)
(defn create
  (println "resourceX/create"))

(ns test)
(myns.resourceX/create)
(myns.resourceY/create)
```

(You can imagine having `resourceX`, `resourceY`, `resourceZ`, etc. The actual `create` functions end up sending HTTP POSTs and returning the response, but this does not matter here.)

Now, in another namespace, I would like to define a function that takes two arguments: an array of resource names (i.e., namespace name) and function name, e.g.:

```
(defn do-verb
   [verb res-type]
   (??))
```

So I can write:

```
(do-verb :create :resourceX)
```

to the same effect as:

```
(myns.resourceX/create)
```

One thing I tried is using `ns-resolve`, e.g.:

`(defn do-verb
  [verb res-type & params]
  (apply (ns-resolve
          (symbol (clojure.string/join ["myns." (name res-type)]))
            (symbol (name verb)))
         params))`

But I am unsure about using `ns-resolve` -- seems like a hack.

Another possibility I have explored is defining a map to associate symbols to functions:

```
(def convert-fns
  {:resourceX {:create resourceX/create}
   :resourceY {:create resourceY/create}
  ...})

(defn do-verb [verb res-type & params]
  (apply (get-in convert-fns [res-type verb]) params))
```

But this has the downside, for me, of requiring to modify `convert-fns` each time a new resource is added.

Are there any alternative approaches to these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do dynamic lookup in namespaces, you may use `ns-publics` function.

See the following snippet:

```
(defn do-verb [verb res-type & params]
  (let [ns-symbol (symbol (str "myns." (name res-type)))
        publics (ns-publics ns-symbol)

        ;; Looking up function we need
        func (publics (symbol (name verb)))]
    (apply func params)))
```

However, this still seems a bit hacky, same as with usage of `ns-resolve`.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to make your `do-verb` function a multimethod.

```
(defmulti do-verb (fn [verb res-type & args] [verb res-type]))
```

After, implement `do-verb` for each of yours `verb`s and resource types:

```
(defmethod do-verb [:create :resourceX] [_ _ & args] ...)
```

And call it as follows:

```
(do-verb :create :resourceX ...)
```

As you can see signatures match perfectly.

Comment: thats a nice approach, one thing about this which I like is that you could define `(defmethod do-verb :default [_ _ & args] ...)` as a 'catch-undefined' clause

Comment: As you say, `ns-publics` sounds as "hacky" as `ns-resolve`. `defmethod`, while an interesting approach, suffers from the requirement of having to add a new specialisation for every new resource type... but thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @sergio I believe that "`ns-publics`" approach is the least hacky we can get, because it does exactly what is written in title of this question: dynamically looks up the function in namespace.

Comment: it might well be the case... I will wait a little more before accepting an answer. Could you elaborate a bit on the difference you see between `ns-resolve` and `ns-publics`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

a macro should be able to do that,

But be very careful with the following code - I never written a (sensible) macro before, so while this seems to work it is not tested and there'll probably be gotchas:

Also note that "user." is hardcoded.

```
; in user ns
user=> (defmacro do-verb [n r] 
         (list (symbol (str "user." (name r) "/" (name n)))))

; quick test
user=> (macroexpand '(do-verb :x :b))
; (user.b/x)

; create a fn in user.b
user.b=> (defn x [] "yay")

; execute new macro
user=> (do-verb :x :b) ; calls (user.b/x)
"yay"
```

Comment: this works -- it works even it `do-verb` is defined as a function and not as a macro. this feels even more hacky than using ns-resolve, to say the truth. in any case, thank you very much.